# Проблемы с установкой Java bridge for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, angularjs

Всем доброго дня! Стоит задача задействовать функционал Java-приложения из веб-приложения (Angular 2 + TS). Хочу задействовать мост node-java, как я понимаю это стандартное решение такой задачи. Никак не удается инсталлировать node-java, установка слетает с ошибками такими:

```
  C:\Users\pomaz\.node-gyp\6.9.5\include\node\v8.h(2954): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::SetHiddenValue'
 d:\prepayment_primeng\node_modules\java\node_modules\nan\nan_new.h(214):           warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of d
 ata (compiling source file ..\src\utils.cpp)     [D:\prepayment_primeng\node_modules\java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
..\src\utils.cpp(750): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> Nan::New<v8::String,const _Elem*,unsigned __i
nt64>(A0,std::A1)' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          A0=const char *,
          A1=unsigned __int64
      ]
 Creating library    D:\prepayment_primeng\node_modules\java\build\Release\nodejavabridge_bindings.lib and object D:\prepayment_primeng\node_modules\jav
  a\build\Release\nodejavabridge_bindings.exp
java.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM [D:\prepayment_primeng\node_modules\java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxpro
j]
 D:\prepayment_primeng\node_modules\java\build\Release\nodejavabridge_bindings.no de : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   [D:\prepayment_primeng\node_modules\java\build\nodejavabridge_bindings.vcxproj]
```

Я учел все рекомендации - наличие VS 2017 (хотя сомневаюсь, нужна ли именно такая версия), MS SDK, JDK 6.45, выставил пути доступа как рекомендуется

```
npm config set python /Python27/python.exe --global
npm config set msvs_version 2010 --global
```

Также на всякий случай поставил windows-build-tools, но все равно не работает команда node-gyp rebuild, выдается такая ошибка и на этом все:

```
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: D:\prepayment_primeng) while trying to load binding.gyp
```

ОС на ПК - Windows Seven 64-bit. Что я делаю не так? Может кто-то сталкивался с чем-то подобным, как выходили из ситуации? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать 32хбитную версию nodejs, также вам необходимо использовать 32хбитную jdk, с 64битами вообще проблемы у node-java

Comment: Дополнительно изучив весь вопрос нашел наиболее частые затыки: 1. Архитектура `JDK` и `node.js` должна быть одинакова, иначе линкер не сможет подключить `jvm` 2. Также желательно использовать python и build-tools той же архитектуры 3. Используйте `c++ build tools` [отсюда](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) при сборке можно указать `--msvs_version=2015`